# Making mobs invincible

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to make mobs invincible? I have already spent a while looking for it on google, but all I get is people telling me to give it a resistance potion effect. I am sure there is some attribute that I can give a summoned mob to make it invincible, but I don't know how to do it. How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, you can give them an invisibility potion effect, either using an actual potion or using the `/effect` command with the `@e` selector in 1.8 (snapshots)

Comment: @MBraedley He's asking about being "invincible" not "invisible" (I did the same thing at first glance)

Comment: Oh, yes, I see that now.  It should still be possible with potion effects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For simply making mobs invincible, this method is now outdated, see [David Toh's solution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166170/30879) using the new "Invulnerable" tag.

---

You need to use a resistance effect of level 5 or higher. This is the closest to a simple invincible tag we have at the moment, it gives the mob 100% resistance to damage, so is effectively the same thing. To summon a mob with an effect, you use the tags

```
{ActiveEffects:[{Id: x ,Amplifier: x ,Durat­ion: x }]}
```

So for an invincible skeleton, you would say:

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~2 ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:5,Durat­ion:10000000}]}
```

The only way to kill this mob will then be either through mods, or using void damage (falling out of the world).

**Extra Note: The mob may still de-spawn if it's not in a loaded area, to avoid this you can name your mob:**

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~2 ~ {CustomName:Example Name,CustomNameVisible:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:5,Durat­ion:10000000}]}
```

Replace "Example Name" with a name of your choice.

**In answer to the comment about using multiple effects:**

You can have as many effects as you like by formatting your active effects section of the summon like so:

```
ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:5,Durat­ion:10000000},{‌​Id:14,Amplifier:1,Durati­on:10000000}]
```

Full command for invincible and invisible skeleton named "Example Name"

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~2 ~ {CustomName:Example Name,CustomNameVisible:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:5,Durat­ion:10000000},{‌​Id:14,Amplifier:1,Durati­on:10000000}]}
```

Comment: How could I make the mob invisible too? (Sorry if this is annoying) Would I add another section that is surrounded by the __[{}]__ characters and separate the two sections of __[{}]__ with a comma like this? __[{}],[{}]__ Or like this? __[{},{}]__

Comment: To add multiple effects, you add another set of {} into the active effects, like so: `/summon Skeleton ~ ~2 ~ {CustomName:Example Name,CustomNameVisible:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:5,Durat­ion:10000000},{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Durati­on:10000000}]}`

Comment: I'll add this to the answer so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 12):

The answer is way simpler now you can now make mobs ***FULLY*** invincible. Here's how:

```
/summon Cow ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```

Easy! If you want to spawn any other mob, just change the "Cow" to the name of whatever mob you like. If you were to spawn a zombie, the zombie will still burn in daylight but will not take any damage from it.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** When typing out the command, the mob's name must be ***EXACT***. For example if I wanted to spawn a zombie, I cant type:

```
/summon zombie ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```

You will just receive the message: "Unable to summon object". Instead, you have to type the name of the mob with ***ALL NECESSARY CAPS***:

```
/summon Zombie ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```

OR

```
/summon Skeleton ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```

mobs with two names will have their own name, e.g: zombie pigman :PigZombie, snow golem :SnowMan iron golem : VillagerGolem cave spider : CaveSpider  magma cube : LavaSlime ender dragon : EnderDragon.

Comment: And also, for mobs like zombie pigmen, I think you could just type in __Zombie_Pigman__, or __ZombiePigman__. I don't think it would prevent you from spawning two word name mobs.

Comment: A player still is able to hurt an "invulnerable" mob if they are in Creative mode.  Switch to Survival or Adventure to test.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DBS for answering my question. For those who are wondering, this is what I was trying to accomplish with this newly gained knowledge. A flying boat. Here is the full command for those who want it:

```
/summon Boat ~ ~ ~ {riding:{Id:Bat{CustomName:Plane,CustomNameVisible:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:5,Duration:372000},{Id:14,Amplifier:5,Duration:372000},{Id:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:372000},{Id:2,Amplifier:255,Duration:2}]}}}
```