# Freezing all mobs, testing for a player in a boat, then unfreezing all mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way that I can freeze all mobs using a command, then test for a player getting on a boat, then unfreeze all the entities? If you are curious as to why I would be wondering this, here is a link to one of my other questions: [Making mobs invincible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165923/making-mobs-invincible/165925?noredirect=1#comment222544_165925)

Comment: So I understand what it is you want to do, you want your bats to be motionless until someone gets in a boat that's riding said bat?  Rewording your question to better reflect your general problem might yield better answers.

Comment: This is a pretty complicated problem, I would suggest freezing all mobs isn't the way to go. Instead possibly spawning a thrown potion of slowness with infinite time as the mob is spawned. Then clearing the effects once you detect the player is in the boat (Still trying to think of a way to detect that)

Comment: Actually, given how the plane is made, clearing effects would break it. Unfortunately I don't know of any other way to freeze it in place.

Comment: @DBS actually, I found a way to do this, just give the bat a potion of slowness effect set to 255 for a few seconds to give the rider time to get on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the /effect command to apply slowness to every entity with a really high level and time as such:

```
/effect @e 2 1000000 255 true
```

Then when you detect your player in the boat (this is where my knowledge ends), you can clear the effect as such:

```
/effect @e clear
```

Comment: Note that using a straight `@e` selector is going to cycle through every entity in existence, including those that cannot accept potion effects. A quick way to target only 'living' mobs is to supply the `team` parameter. For example, leaving it blank (`@e[team=]`) will target living entities not on a team. Alternatively, the mobs that should be affected could be added to a specific team. You should also be using name IDs instead of numerical ("slowness" rather than "2").