# Summoning invincible boats and minecarts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way that I can summon an invincible minecart and or boat? These are some methods that I think **might** work, but I haven't had time to test.

```
/summon Boat ~ ~ ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:255,Duration:37200}]}

/summon MinecartRideable ~ ~ ~ {ActiveEffects:
[{Id:11,Amplifier:255,Duration:37200}]}
```

So, is this the correct way, or am I doing it wrong? If I am doing it wrong, please tell me the correct method. Thanks! Also, for those curious as to why I might wonder this, here is a link to one of my other questions. [Making mobs invincible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165923/making-mobs-invincible) (Just look at my answer to my own question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found just the right command for you!

**To spawn an invincible minecart:**

```
   /summon Minecart ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```

This spawns an invincible minecart right next to you. However, you are unable to place the minecart on a track as it is invincible and you cannot pick it up. Not even in creative mode.

**To spawn an invincible boat:**

```
/summon Boat ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```

This spawns an invincible boat next to you. I recommend that you do so while in water as the boat may sometimes spawn on land, making it useless (technically).

However, while trying out these commands, I realised that both the boat and minecart are invincible to TNT, lava, creepers etc. Sadly, the boat still breaks down if you hit a block or mob while riding it at high speeds.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** When typing out the command, the mob's name must be ***EXACT***. For example if I wanted to spawn a boat, I cant type:

```
/summon boat ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```

You will just receive the message: "Unable to summon object". Instead, you have to type the name of the mob with ***ALL NECESSARY CAPS***:

```
/summon Boat ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```

OR

```
/summon Minecart ~0 ~0 ~0 {Invulnerable:1}
```